# Does anyone know a fix to "pptx.exc.PackageNotFoundError:" when running an exe file built out of a python script with Presentation() object?

Tags: python, exe, python-pptx

I wrote a python script that collects images and places them one slide at a time in a PowerPoint presentation. This script works fine when it is run using ".py" file. I then built an exe file using this python script. When running that ".exe" file, it always gives me an error at the line where **Presentation()** object is called. The error is captured in the image below:
[Error that is encountered when running an exe file that was built using pyinstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMnod.png)

The python script that I am testing is as simple as follows:

[main.py]

```
import collections
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation

myPresentation = Presentation()
```

The command I used to build exe file out of this script was:

```
pyinstaller main.py --onefile
```

Please help me if you have any solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the exe version can't find the base presentation (shipped with python-pptx).

Comment: I am not sure how to solve that if it can be solved, could you please help?

Comment: I just decided to have a default.pptx file next to the exe file and use it as the template.

Comment: What happens if you pass in explicitly a presentation you already have? The compiled version might well find it. Then you'd know if it was a case of not finding the built-in one.

Comment: @MartinPacker That is what I ended up doing. The package somehow isn’t able to find/use the built in template pptx file. So, I gave it a new “default.pptx” which the package was able to use. Thanks for your help!